# Ionic 3 serve showing a different line of code in error?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am running `ionic serve` and it shows an error:

```
[10:53:49]  typescript: src/pages/tab-feed/schedule.ts, line: 50
        Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
  L50:     this.logService.getFeed().map(data => data.json())
```

However, my line of code is actually:

```
  L50: this.token = token;
  L51: this.logService.getFeed(this.token).map(data => data.json())
```

Why does my build show this error?

EDIT: 
**Solved.** My issue was that a component I made via the CLI messed something up. After rolling back a version without that component, the app not works as expected.